# Can't create SceneKit particle system resource file with "Leafs" template in Xcode 7.2, workarounds?

Tags: xcode, scenekit, particle-system

recently we have been trying to create a SceneKit particle resource file using "Leafs" template. Seems like a easy job to do at first but we failed. We can create the file with any other templates but not "Leafs". It fails every time. After the wizard dialog closed, nothing has been created.

Question, is there a workaround? For example, maybe we can create a resource file using another template say "rain" and change the parameters manually? If so, how?

Comment: Dev forums show that this template doesn't work, but as it only sets up initial values you should be able to create your own. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/31021